# Render images in Array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, create-react-app

I've a JSON Schema which has Array of images which I need to render into a carousel in ReactJS.

`api.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": "DR001",
    "propertyFullName": "8838, Brook St, NY",
    "propertyShortName": "Anchorage, AK 99501",
    "features": ["2 beds", "1 bath", "865 sqft"],
    "description": "data.",
    "images": [
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"
    ],
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": "DR002",
    "propertyFullName": "8838, Brook St, NY",
    "propertyShortName": "Anchorage, AK 99501",
    "features": ["2 beds", "1 bath", "865 sqft"],
    "description": "data.",
    "images": [
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"
    ]
  }
]
```

I am hard-coding the first array i.e. `features` like this

```
{APIData.map((apiData, index) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <Heading subtitle>
                        <span name={index}>{apiData.features[0]}</span>
                        <span class="middle-dot" aria-hidden="true">
                          &nbsp;
                        </span>
                        <span>{apiData.features[1]}</span>
                        <span class="middle-dot" aria-hidden="true">
                          &nbsp;
                        </span>
                        <span>{apiData.features[2]}</span> <br />
                        <span>
                          <p>{apiData.description}</p>
                        </span>
                      </Heading>
                      <hr />
                    </>
                  );
                })}
```

Because, I know there will be only 3 features, but in case of `images`, it is dynamic. How come I overcome this?

The images are rendering in an other `<div>`, I've tried something like this

```
            <Carousel {...settings}>
              {APIData.map((images, index) => {
                return (
                  <>{<img src={images.images} alt={index} />}</>
                );
              })}
            </Carousel>
```

Comment: You can use another `map()` inside your `<Heading />` component to iterate through all the images available.

Comment: You have to run map inside the map you already have. Create a separate function and pass images to it from the above map where you map over the images And return the array and call that function inside the map you have above.

Comment: @AlexSanchez Sorry, I forgot to mention that images are in another `<div>`, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you already had, it will end up something like this to iterate through the images for every property:

```js
<Carousel {...settings}>
  {APIData.map((data, index) => {
     data.images.map((image, index) => {
        return <img key={index} src={image} alt={index} />
     } 
  })}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: Don't you think we'll have to map the entire carousel because this is conflicting with the above code (maybe) and resulting 2 sliders vertically showing all images in it together

Comment: Doing this will initialize the slide only once and I want to show images in slider for each Object in JSON

Comment: @YashKaranke I don't have any insight of the functionality of your app, I just posted an example to render multiples images depending of the content of the array (which was what you were asking for). If you wanted to create more, you'll need to declare a Carousel component next to your Heading component and map it too of course.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a stateless component and render it inside the original `map`, like this

```
const Images = ({list}) => list.map(image => <img src={image}/>);

myArr.map(item => // some DOM here, and, at last: <Images list={item.images}>)
```

You know, not to repeat a `map` call inside another one, which, in my opinion, looks a bit ugly

Comment: You should add a key prop too

Comment: Well, you are right, but I don't think it is relevant to the question, so I just omitted that for the sake of brevity